# Get the current effective date from the list of records has past and future dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having list of records with a column `EffectiveOn` in SQL Server database table. I want to fetch the currently applicable `EffectiveOn` respective to current date. Consider the following table

```
Id         Data        EffectiveOn
_____________________________________
1          abc         2020-04-28
2          xyz         2020-08-05
3          dhd         2020-10-30
4          ert         2020-12-28
5          lkj         2021-03-19
```

In the above table I have to fetch the record (`Id: 3`) because the current date (i.e., today) is `2020-11-19`

Expected Resultset

```
Id         Data        EffectiveOn
_____________________________________
3          dhd         2020-10-30
```

I tried the following solution but I can't [How do I get the current records based on it's Effective Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618019/how-do-i-get-the-current-records-based-on-its-effective-date)

Kindly assist me how to get the expected result-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select top (1) *
from mytable t
where effectiveon <= convert(date, getdate())
order by effectiveon desc
```

This selects the greatest date before today (or today, if available).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Row_number function

```
select id, data, effectiveon 
( 
    select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by effectiveon desc )sno,* from #table 
    where effectiveon < cast(getdate() as date)
)a where sno=1
```